# Manacher's algorithm in Scilab

Tags: scilab

I've code that I put below, could anyone help me understand what is going on here?

```
x = "10100111000";
n = length(x);
lgmax = 0;
pos = 0;

for i = 1:n-1
    // k=0: odd sequence, k=1: even sequence
    for k = 0:1
        j=1;
        while j <= min(i-1+k,n-i) && part(x,i+j) == part(x,i-j+k)
            j = j+1;
        end
        if 2*j-1-k > lgmax
            lgmax = 2*j-1-k;
            pos = i-j+1+k;
        end
     end
 end

 disp(part(x,pos:pos+lgmax-1))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code, maybe you found it in another Stackoverflow thread ? What is your problem with it ? With the definition of x on the top of the program the output is

```
"0011100"
```

which IS the longest palindrom of your sequence.

Comment: Hi, im struggling with understanding what is happening in this line

`for k = 0:1
        j=1;
        while j <= min(i-1+k,n-i) && part(x,i+j) == part(x,i-j+k)
            j = j+1;
        end`

What i mean by this is what exactly is K, why J=1 at the start and what is happening in those ( ) - why are we looking for min(i-1+k,n-1) - what does it give us? What is (x, i+j) and why do we compare it to (x, i-j+k)? I understand that these are some digits from our x but why do they have to be equal? And why do we add 1 to J if the above are >= J?

Comment: Also here 
`if 2*j-1-k > lgmax
            lgmax = 2*j-1-k;
            pos = i-j+1+k;`
What does 2*j-1-k stand for?

Comment: You  just need to know what does `part()`. To this purpose type `help part`at Scilab prompt. Then, you should be able to follow all loops by hand.

Comment: And (disclaimer) my code does not implement Manacher's algorithm ! See the following page: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/manachers-algorithm-linear-time-longest-palindromic-substring-part-1/